# How to create and assign a variable within a map() which is in render()?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, uuid

Below is the code I am working on (I have trimmed it down to make it readable).

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Table.Row>

        { MONTHS.map(month => [ // live forecast, actuals and vs forecasts cells per month
          <Table.Cell className="live-forecast-cell">
            <Input
              ref={el => { this.inputRef[uuid()] = el; }}
              onFocus={e => this.handleLiveForecastFocus(supplierName, month, e)}
            />
          </Table.Cell>,
        ]) }
      </Table.Row>
    );
  }
```

In the map operation, I generate a [uuid()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) value for the ref. I need to then pass this same ref value to the onFocus handler method. How can I achieve this? Appreciate any advice.

Comment: You can create a method outside of the `render` method. Do all your logic related to `uuid` and utilize that method for `onFocus` call within the `Input` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use closure

```js
render() {
  return (
    <Table.Row>

      { MONTHS.map(month => {
        const id = uuid();
        return [ // live forecast, actuals and vs forecasts cells per month
        <Table.Cell className="live-forecast-cell">
          <Input
            ref={el => { this.inputRef[id] = el; }}
            onFocus={e => {
              this.handleLiveForecastFocus(supplierName, month, e);
              // this.inputRef[id]
            }}
          />
        </Table.Cell>,
      ];}) }
    </Table.Row>
  );
}
```

2. You can inspect that `e` argument in your `onFocus` handler - that object has refrence to DOM element (something like e.target )

Comment: The first answer solved my problem. However, for those who come across the same scenario i.e. generating element refs using UUID, using UUID did not work due to the random generation

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
  return (
    <Table.Row>
    { MONTHS.map(month => { // live forecast, actuals and vs forecasts cells per month
      const uuidValue = uuid()
      return (
        <Table.Cell className="live-forecast-cell" key={'ADD_A_UNIQUE_KEY_HERE'}>
          <Input
            ref={el => { this.inputRef[uuidValue] = el; }}
            onFocus={e => this.handleLiveForecastFocus(supplierName, month, e, uuidValue)} 
          />
        </Table.Cell>
      )
    }) }
  </Table.Row>
);
}
```